# Diferença entre printf e format

Tags: java, string

Existe alguma diferença entre usar o `printf` e o `format`?

Exemplo 01:

```
float nota = 5.3f
System.out.printf ("Sua nota: %.2f", nota)
```

Exemplo 02:

```
float nota = 5.3f
System.out.format ("Sua nota: %.2f", nota)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

> A convenience method to write a formatted string to this output stream
>   using the specified format string and arguments.   An invocation of
>   this method of the form `out.printf(format, args)` behaves in exactly
>   the same way as the invocation `out.format(format, args)`

Ou seja, não há diferença, pois o `out.printf` é apenas uma forma diferente de invocar o `out.format`.

Fuçando o código fonte da versão open source do java(OpenJDK), o que ocorre é que o `printf` faz uma chamada para o `format` e mais nada:

```
 public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ...args) {
     return format(format, args);
 }
```

fonte: [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.printf%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)